# NumPy "Too many indices for array" error whilst predicting from neural network

Tags: arrays, numpy, keras, neural-network, python-3.7

I have a text file with data:

```
0,13,10,10,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,13,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,10,10,11,11,11,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,14,14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

I need to get it into an array so I can use my neural network to predict the output. 
However when I use the code:

```
predict_data = input("Enter the file name of the test scan: ")
inputdata = loadtxt(predict_data, delimiter=',')
np.arange(151).reshape(1,151)
z = inputdata[:,150]
model.predict(z, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None, callbacks=None, max_queue_size=10, workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False)
```

I get the error:

```
z = inputdata[:,150]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Sorry if this is messy I'm new to this website.

Comment: Why are you using `np.arange(151).reshape(1,151)` ?

Comment: Trying to change the array from one dimensional to 2 dimensional as that is what the model is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Your input array is one-dimensional but when you do:

```
z = inputdata[:,150]
```

You are treating it as a 2d array (you are trying to extract the 151th column of `input_data`).

Comment: How do I get it to accept 1 row with 151 columns? I trained the module with 15 lines of 151 columns. But I need the predictor to only accept 1 row instead of 15 so it can predict what it is.

Comment: Oh I see what you did there, you forgot the `inputdata =` before reshaping on line 3